# How to force Entity Framework insert records to clean database every solution run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, seeding

Before answer, please read whole question. All the stuff in the tutorials, stack **overflow** topics does NOT work.

I try to force entity framework to insert records into database every time I run debuggin programm even if there were no changes at all. This means that if I make any changes during last run they will be gone. This is not happenning.

My Global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_Start() {

            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<PersonContext, Configuration>()); 
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PersonContext>());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

My Web.config Entity Framework section:

```
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
     <context type="WebApplication2.Models.PersonContext, WebApplication2">
        <databaseInitializer type="WebApplication2.Models.PersonInitializer, WebApplication2" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

My seed method:

```
   protected override void Seed(PersonContext context) {
            var persons = new List<Person> { 
             new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying"},
             new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "113-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying"}
            };

            persons.ForEach(person => context.Persons.Add(person));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var meetings = new List<Meeting>{
                new Meeting{PersonId = 1, Body = "Body of meeting", Date = DateTime.Now}
            };

            meetings.ForEach(meeting => context.Meetings.Add(meeting));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var statuses = new List<Status> {
                new Status{Name = "OK"},
                new Status {Name = "NOT_OK"}
            };

            statuses.ForEach(status => context.Statuses.Add(status));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication2.Models {
    public class PersonInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PersonContext> {
        protected override void Seed(PersonContext context) {
            var persons = new List<Person> { 
             new Person{FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "123-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "312312312", Notes = "Annoying"},
             new Person{FirstName = "Anna", LastName = "Doe", CellNumber = "113-456-789", SecondaryPhoneNumber = "98873213", Address = "1street 2",BirthDate = DateTime.Now.Date, Pesel = "548555672", Notes = "Less Annoying"}
            };

            persons.ForEach(person => context.Persons.Add(person));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var meetings = new List<Meeting>{
                new Meeting{PersonId = 1, Body = "Body of meeting", Date = DateTime.Now}
            };

            meetings.ForEach(meeting => context.Meetings.Add(meeting));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var statuses = new List<Status> {
                new Status{Name = "OK"},
                new Status {Name = "NOT_OK"}
            };

            statuses.ForEach(status => context.Statuses.Add(status));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the class name that contains `Seed` method and what is the base class of that class?

Comment: @YuliamChandra I posted full class code in the EDIT in OP. The Seed method is invoked after doing migrations, so I have this data in the database, but I want it always to be invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
public class PersonInitializer :
   System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PersonContext>
```

with

```
public class PersonInitializer :
   System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PersonContext>
```

This code will always drop, recreate and seed the database.

PS: I think the initializer in the config is the priority.